# Apache Airflow | Use case for an "Ansible operator"

Tags: automation, ansible, airflow, workflow, cicd

I am a fun of Ansible for IT tasks automation, testing, CI/CD, provisioning, inventorying, no-code/configuration over code approach, etc. ...

.. I also like the way Airflow handles triggers and different workflow exiting/concatenation logic, notifications, and keep tracks of past runs

... so I am wondering, is there any use case for using both technologies together? (i mean embedding ansible inside airflow)

A quick web search just leads me to stuff like "Ansible VS Airflow", but i see potential for using them both without having to rewrite all Ansible playbooks into python code.

I am quite surprised not to see any Ansible operator for Airflow out there, could you share some thoughts on this?

Comment: I was asking myself the same question lately. Doesn't seem like anyone has publicly discussed an "Ansible operator"

Comment: Could be because Airflow and Ansible could be seen as competing frameworks and thus operators regard them as "either/or" solutions. I would update this post in case i get my hands on anything new

Comment: @energenious no its because two different user bases use ansible and airflow. Most for one reason or another think ansible is *only* for configuration of operating systems (its more than that) and airflow is seen mostly as a data engineer's tool or replacement for the mainframe. Now one can use the Docker Operator and https://hub.docker.com/r/ansible/ansible image to have ansible playbooks scheduled within airflow.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use it if it existed but overall one can use the Docker Operator and https://hub.docker.com/r/ansible/ansible image to have ansible playbooks scheduled within airflow.